# AngularJS: Create tab links by creating the tab's content in the DOM

Tags: angularjs

I'm new to AngularJS,
Sorry if this is a silly question. 
I googled quite a lot and I can't find existing help online.

Basically, I'm trying to generate the tab headers dynamically by creating the content sections.

I have no idea how to go about it.
Simply pointing me in the right direction would be a lot of help!

I want to implement in my code something like this

```
<div ng-show="panel[this].isSelected" ng-attr-title="JS">
    lorem ipsum...
</div>
<div ng-show="panel[this].isSelected" ng-attr-title="C#">
    lorem ipsum...
</div>
<div ng-show="panel[this].isSelected" ng-attr-title="Node">
    lorem ipsum...
</div>
```

And generate the tabs using ng-repeat automatically. 
Expected output:

```
JS | C# | Node
```

Any tips on where to begin?

Answer (score 1):

```
<div ng-repeat="panel in panels" ng-class="{'selected': panel.selected}" ng-attr-title="{{panel.title}}">
    lorem ipsum...
</div>

<script>
//...
    $scope.panels = [{'title': 'JS', selected: false}, {'title': 'C#', selected: false}, {'title': 'Node', selected: true}]
//...
<script>
```

you probably need this, check the api doc [ng-repeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) and [ng-class](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass)

Comment: My friend! thank you for your answer, though, in your solution I still need to manually name the tabs. I'm looking for a way to deduce the tabs by generating the divs with contents themselves.

Comment: In my example I created 3 divs. each with a ng-attr-title. Can I autogenerate the tabs only based on the title attribute I created for the content divs?